# Mac Python pointing to different site-packages after python upgrade - How do i point all site-packages to correct python version?

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to upgrade my Mac from 2.6 to 2.7 and everything went fine except for some libraries are being used from 2.6 now instead of 2.7, any idea how I can point all the new libraries to 2.7?  Basically I am trying to install yolk for 2.7 but it says that its already installed (under 2.6).

```
$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
[~, kamilski81_macbook@mac]
$ which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install
[~, kamilski81_macbook@mac]
$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
[~, kamilski81_macbook@mac]
$ which yolk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/yolk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the evidence you present, it appears you have both of the framework bin directories of Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 on your shell search path, `$PATH`.  If you used the python.org installers to install both 2.6 and 2.7, each installer by default modifies your shell startup files to include the bin directory it installed on `$PATH`. For example:

```
$ more ~/.bash_profile
[...]

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

It looks you've done the right thing of installing `pip` and `easy_install` in your 2.7 instance.  You should be able to use that `pip` or that `easy_install` to install `yolk` for 2.7.  There is nothing wrong with having both framework bins on your `$PATH`; this is one of the advantages of the Python framework installation scheme for Mac OS X.  The files that Python itself installs in those bin directories are generally installed as a versioned file name, like `python2.7`, with a symlink to its unversioned name, `python`.  The versioned names will be unique across all of the framework bin directories; which unversioned one is used will depend upon the order in which the bin directories appear in `$PATH`.  For third-party packages with scripts, like `yolk`, the script name is not automatically versioned so you can end up with a `yolk` in multiple bin directories if you install it multiple times.

If your end goal is to only have one version of Python, you can modify your shell startup file (`.bash_profile`, `.profile` et al) to remove the references to 2.6.  If you want you can delete the 2.6 files in the framework altogether.

If you want to retain both versions of Python and have a `yolk` command for each, either change your shell $PATH as necessary to ensure the desired version comes first (an awkward solution) or create shell aliases to the absolute paths of the duplicated commands, or create a versioned symlink in each of the framework bin directories:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
$ ln -s yolk yolk2.6
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
$ ln -s yolk yolk2.7
$ which yolk2.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/yolk2.6
$ which yolk2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/yolk2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

First, verify if yolk isn't installed in `Version/2.7/site-packages`. If it is not then you need to tell pip which python version to install to:

```
pip -E /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python yolk
```

If it is then it is a problem with you path settings, and need to change the `PATH` variable appropriately.